# how to save data in conversation for telegram bot conversationHandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am building a telegram bot.

one of the functionalities of my bot require the bot to query the user to pick between choices.
Hear is my code that query the user

```
def entry_point(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    companies_btn = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(company.company_name, callback_data=company.id)
            for company in get_companies()
        ]
    ]
    companies_keyword = InlineKeyboardMarkup(companies_btn)
    update.message.reply_text(
        "Please pick a company", reply_markup=companies_keyword
    )
    return 1


def user_picked_company(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    stores_btn = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(store.store_name, callback_data=store.id)
            for store in get_stores()
        ]
    ]

    store_keyword = InlineKeyboardMarkup(stores_btn)
    update.message.reply_text(
        "Please pick a store", reply_markup=store_keyword
    )
    return 2


def user_picked_store(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    save_user_choices()


handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('pick', entry_point)],
    states={
        1: CallbackQueryHandler(user_picked_company),
        2: CallbackQueryHandler(user_picked_store)
    },
    fallbacks=[entry_point],
    per_chat=True,
    per_user=True,
    per_message=True
)
```

as you can see, in the function `user_picked_store` I need to save the user choices (I can save in the db only after the user picked all the information).
Therefore I need access to the all the choices the user made, I thought to store it in an object outside the function and so all the function can use it, however this solution will not work if multiple request will be made at the same time (each request will override the other).

Is there a way to save a state for each instance of the conversation?

Is there any session id for each conversation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have `context.user_data` dict that is persistent acrross conversation, you can use it to store there all user choices.

e.g.

```
query = update.callback_query
querydata = query.data
context.user_data["key"] = querydata
```

Comment: What's lifecycle of `context.user_data` ? Will it clear when the conversation is over? If a user goes to the same entry point again, will it be there?

Comment: @ArtemTrunov i was wondering the same. I guess If we want full persistence maybe we should use a db

Answer (score 0):

Yes the context.user_data holds till the conversation lasts with the user.

To use the context.user_data dict, we need to mention as context.user_data.get('var_name')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).